# Using つける for wearing undies? (Clothes question)

Tags: usage, word-usage

I know it's for accessories that don't fall under head,torso and legs portion of the body. Shouldn't underwear (パンツ) be used with はく？

I saw it in a J-drama where a girl says パンツがつけてない to make the guy get a nosebleed.

Comment: Are you sure she said 「パンツ**が**つけてない」, not 「パンツ**を**つけてない」?

Answer (score 4):

The normal verb for パンツ is はく. パンツをつける is highly unnatural, but パンツを[身につける](https://eow.alc.co.jp/search?q=%E8%BA%AB%E3%81%AB%E7%9D%80%E3%81%91%E3%82%8B&ref=sa) is acceptable (although wordy). I think you have misheard something.

Comment: No mishearing took place. Just a recollection difference from ga to wa and the noun was diff which has no effect on the meaning. http://newasiantv.io/watch/tamiou-episode-3-engsub.592.8373.html at the 45:30 mark.

”下着はつけたない”。

Comment: ^ shoryuu「下着はつけていないのよ」って言ってますよね・・・「パンツがつけてない」とはえらい違いですが・・・。 You know は replaces を, right? 「下着**を**つける」(not 「下着**が**つける」)→「下着**は**つけていない」... and 下着 includes ブラジャーとか...

Comment: I didn't know は replaces を but I を know が replaces を. Oh hey, now they all can replace each other lol.

Good point about underwear being a blanket term. So つけていない is fine with brassiere (which we think is being referred to) as compared to with panties then?

Comment: @shoryuu 下着をつける is fine because 下着 is undergarments in general.

Comment: So you are saying a general word is fine to  use つける？So if I was just generally talking about ふく i can use つける with it too? Like "humans wear clothes in our society (私たちの社会には各人は服をつける）"

Is this just a contraction of your身につける without the 身に?

Comment: @shoryuu 服をつける is wrong, 服を身に着ける is fine (but sounds like "to equip ..."). Please don't over-generalize what I said.